# Calculate the values of $a$, $b$ and $k$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The equation of a curve is $y=ab^x$. Given that the curve passes through $(1, 12), (2,48)$and $(4,k)$. Calculate the values of $a$, $b$ and $k$.

Comment: $(1, 12)$ means $a=1$ and $y=12$?

Comment: Is there a missing $x$ somewhere in the equation?

Comment: Nope, this means $x=1$ and $y=12$ and so on...

Comment: Yeah, corrected it. :) Sorry @AndréNicolas

Comment: Anyway, each point the curve pass gives a equality. So you have three equalities in three variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

we have $12=ab^1$, $48=ab^2$ and $k=ab^4$. From the two first equations we see the multiplying by $b$ multiples the result by 4, so $b=4$.

Comment: I guess you're wrong; it must be $k = (ab)^4$

Comment: @Kiara thanks, corrected.

Comment: How do I multiply the first two equations?

Comment: @Kiara Not multiple, divide the second by the first. Since if $a=b$ and $c=d$ them $a/c=b/d$

Comment: okay, let me try.

Comment: Thank you so much...It's done. :) @LeeNeveGup